# Excel services MSOLAP.8 provider for SSAS OLAP cube

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-services, sql-analysis-services

I have an Excel file in SharePoint 2013.
This file has an underlying connection to SSAS OLAP cube.
However, when trying to open this file using Excel Services, the following error occurs:

```
 The workbook 'http://myapplications07/Shared Documents/InventoryTest.xlsx' attempted to access external data using the unsupported provider 
    'Provider=MSOLAP.8;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXX;Data Source=XXXXXXXX.com;MDX Compatibility=1;Safety 
    Options=2;MDX Missing Member Mode=Error;Update Isolation Level=2'. [Session: 1.V22.53DCtM3PdhzjoYc1LCLNOb14.5.en-US5.en-US36.8c8a7685-b35e-4451-ae7e-984da390a1401.A1.N User: 0#.w|XXXXXX\ssolovyev1]

11/22/2017 10:45:16.76  w3wp.exe (0x1BB4)   0x0808  Excel Services Application  Excel Calculation Services  3sls    Medium  ExternalSource.ValidateConnection: Unable to get a connection: Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.Interop.ConnectionException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.Interop.ConnectionException' was thrown.     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ConnectionManager.ValidateConnectionInfo(ConnectionRequest connectionRequest, ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ConnectionManager.GetConnection(ConnectionRequest connectionRequest, ExtendedConnectionInfo extendedConnInfo, Credentials credentials, Int64 privateConnectionId, Boolean auditConnection)     at Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.CalculationServer.ExternalSource.TryGetValidatedConnection(Request request, ConnectionRequest connectionRequest, ExternalDataScenario scenario, Credentials credentials, ExtendedConnectionInfo extendedConnectionInfo, Int64 privateConnectionId, Boolean shouldReportFailure, Connection& connectionOut). sessionId=1.V22.19YbAvTqpvprv44Ask07rN14.5.en-US5.en-US36.8c8a7685-b35e-4451-ae7e-984da390a1401.A1.N, externalSource=XXXXXXX.com Inventory   1c582f9e-add1-a031-948f-5edb46283095
```

When the document is re-created by myself using Excel 2013 (Microsoft Office 365 Pro Plus 15.0.4981.1000), "Provider" parameter is changed to MSOLAP.5 and I'm able to open the file using Excel Services.

Quick search @google gives me only one suggestion:

> Office 365 use their own MSOLAP.8 installed in `Program Files
>   x86\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesX86\Microsoft Analysis
>   Services\AS OLEDB\140\`
>   And MSOLAP.8 (Microsoft OLE DB Provider for
>   Analysis Services 14.0) is from Office365 ( Version 1705 - Build
>   8201.2102 Click-to-Run).

Alas, I have no idea how to bypass this behavior on SharePoint box without installing Office 365 on it.

P.S. Adding MSOLAP.8 in Excel Services configuration doesn't work as well as adding registry key to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\ClickToRun\REGISTRY\MACHINE\Software\Classes\<...>]`

**Update:**

Excel version on the machine: Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO 16.0.6925.1018 (latest update 16.0.6965.2058), msolap110.dll version is 11.110.9167.412